# Parse JSON response with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, swifty-json

I have the following code and I am trying to get values using SwiftyJSON:

```
let string =
    """
        {"ResponseMetadata": {"RequestId": "b5d6ecad-e050-4d1f-8429-74a2775a6fe9", "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": {"x-amzn-requestid": "b5d6ecad-e050-4d1f-8429-74a2775a6fe9", "content-type": "application/json", "content-length": "271", "date": "Tue, 22 Dec 2020 22:45:17 GMT"}, "RetryAttempts": 0}, "numberOfRecordsUpdated": 0, "records": [[{"stringValue": "6998DFFE-A9CF-4BEA-86AD-C356BB865E27"}, {"stringValue": "david.craine@yahoo.com"}, {"stringValue": "David"}, {"stringValue": "Craine"}, {"stringValue": "dcraine"}, {"stringValue": "vendor1"}, {"stringValue": "vendor1_werw8"}]]}
    """
    
let body = JSON(string)
print(">>>>>>>>> \(body["records"])")
```

This returns null for body["records"].

I validated this response using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#, so I am assuming it is in the correct format. Can anyone help please?

Comment: "Yet, when I try to get any items (e.g "records") it returns null" And how did you attempt to do that exactly?

Comment: Assuming that the JSON object of the mentioned string is called body , I use body["records"]

Comment: I would recommend you to use Codable & JSONDecoder from Swift, this will allow you to parse and create JSON without using any third party framework

Comment: Try replacing `let body = JSON(string)` with `let body = JSON(parseJSON: string)`.

Comment: Thanks @gcharita it's working! If you post your answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
let body = JSON(string)
```

and call the `init(parseJSON:)` initializer of `JSON` that takes a `String` as parameter, like this:

```
let body = JSON(parseJSON: string)
```